# How to dynamically change webpage content based on input fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dynamic-html

I have a webpage that I am building, and I want it to update some text on the page as a couple input values are changed. Basically, here is my algorithm I think it should follow however I'm not exactly too sure. (to clarify I am using PHP as well) but I dont have any further knowledge of any other languages besides HTML and CSS and a small amount of javascript obviously).

```
Open Amount: $<input type="text" name="openamount"><br />
Close Amount: $<input type="text" name="closeamount"><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("Profit $" + document.getElementsByName("openamount").value - document.getElementsByName("closeamount").value);
</script>
```

Couple of problems, first when the page loaded it gives me a few undefined things when I would rather it just start off as blank, second it doesn't update as I put content into the input fields. On top of all that though, I need the profit actually sent as one of the values in the POST form. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: So all i get on the webpage is undefinedundefinedundefined (thats literally what it says). On my web server error log it doesnt post an error at all.

Comment: Ouch! `document.write()` is ancient! Why not just attach an event handler to your input fields that make an AJAX call for updated content to be injected back into the document?

Comment: Because I have never used AJAX and I didnt quite know what that is? I'll do more research into AJAX. thank you though.

Comment: Take a look here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is running right when the page loads, and never again. Instead of this, you want to hook into the element's change events to run the code whenever they are changed. As for adding the profit to a POST variable, just create a hidden input inside your form that holds the profit value.

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates all this: https://jsfiddle.net/yjvvjq49/

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
  Open Amount: $<input type="text" id="openamount" name="openamount"><br />
  Close Amount: $<input type="text" id="closeamount" name="closeamount"><br />

  <input type="hidden" id="profit" name="profit"/>
  Profit: $<span id="profitText"></span>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var openElement = document.getElementById("openamount");
var closeElement = document.getElementById("closeamount");
var profitElement = document.getElementById("profit");
var profitTextElement = document.getElementById("profitText");

function updateProfit() {
  var profit = (Number(closeElement.value) - Number(openElement.value)).toFixed(2);
  profitElement.value = profit;
  profitTextElement.innerText = profit; 
}

openElement.onchange = closeElement.onchange = updateProfit;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would enclose your document.write in a function, then add an onChange to your inputs to call said function.

Comment: Ohhh okay that makes more sense. On top of that. what would be the best way to make the resulting profit actually sent as an entry in the submission.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I would make an element for profit and do a form.submit (I'm not sure of the syntax for the submit but it can be easily found).

Answer (score -1):

Aside from your javascript, here is the php you may need. Aswell as the form element.

```
<php
if(isset($_POST['openamount']) && isset($_POST['closeamount']))
{
    print "PHP got values " . $_POST['openamount'] . " and " . $_POST['closeamount'];
}
?>



<form method="POST" action="">
    Open Amount: $<input type="text" name="openamount"><br />
    Close Amount: $<input type="text" name="closeamount"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit money">
</form>
```